# Why is the probability that $3$ people will not respond to a survey equal to this?

Tags: probability, probability-theory, statistics

When sent a questionnaire, $50\%$ of the recipients respond immediately.  Of those who do not respond immediately, $40\%$ respond when sent a follow-up letter.  If the questionnaire is sent to $4$ people and a follow-up letter is sent to any of the $4$ people who do not respond immediately, what is the probability that at least $3$ never respond?

Now I know that the probability that an individual will not respond to either the questionnaire or the follow-up letter is $(.5)(.6) = .3$. The probability that all $4$ will not respond to either the questionnaire or the follow-up letter is $(.3)^4$.  That much makes sense.

But I'm also told that the probability that $3$ don't respond is equal to $4[(.5)^4 (.6)^3] + 4[(.5)^4(.6)^3(.4)] = 4(.3)^3(.7)$.

Where do the $4$s and the $.4$ come from in the left side of the equation above?

Comment: Thank you. I hope it's clearer now.  I just can't figure out where that equation at the end is coming from.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your $ 4(.3)^3(.7)$, which might be written as  $4(.3)^3(1-.3)$, is the probability that exactly three do not respond and one person does.

The $4$ coefficient comes from any of the four individuals being the one person who does respond, and choosing one from four has ${4 \choose 1} = 4$ possibilities.

The earlier terms are the one individual either responding initially or after the follow-up.  Again it could be any one of the four.  It could have been written $4[(.5 \times .6)^3 (1-.5)] + 4[(.5 \times .6)^3 (.5 \times (1-.6))]  $